# Multiple Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm not used to them and having trouble with the java syntax "matches".

I have two files one is `111.123.399.555.xml` the other one is `Conf.xml.`

Now I only want to get the first file with regular expressions.

```
string.matches("[1-9[xml[.]]]");
```

doesnt work.

How to do this?

Comment: Do you want `/([1-9]{3}\.){4}xml/` ?

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://xisb.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/what-absolutely-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions/) to give a real brief overview on regular expressions, the absolutely basics, everybody should know. Maybe it helps you to understand some more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `string.matches("[1-9[xml[.]]]");` will not work because `[]` will create a character class group, not a capturing group.

What this means is that, to java, your expression is saying `"match any of: [1-to-9 [or x, or m, or l [or *any*]]]"` (*any* here is because you did not escape the `.`, and as it, it will create `a match any character` command)

---

Important:

"\" is recognized by java as a literal escape character, and for it to be sent to the matcher as an actual matcher's escape character (also "\", but in string form), it itself needs to be escaped, thus, when you mean to use "\" on the matcher, you must actually use "\\".

This is a bit confusing when you are not used to it, but to sum it up, to send an actual **"\" to be matched** to the matcher, you **might have to use "\\\\"**! The first "\\" will become "\" to the matcher, thus a scape character, and the second "\\", escaped by the first, will become the actual "\" string!

---

The correct pattern-string to match for a `###.###.###.###.xml` pattern where the "#" are always numbers, is `string.matches("(\\d{3}\\.){4}xml")`, and how it works is as follows:

- The `\\d` = will match a single digit character. It is the same as
  using `[0-9]`, just simpler.
- The `{3}` specifies matching for "exactly 3 times" for the previous
  `\\d`. Thus matching `###`.
- The `\\.` matches a single dot character.
- The `()` enclosing the previous code says "this is a capturing group"
  to the matcher. It is used by the next `{4}`, thus creating a "match
  this whole `###.` group exactly 4 times", thus creating "match `###.###.###.###.`".
- And finally, the `xml` before the pattern-string ends will match
  exactly "xml", which, along the previous items, makes the exact match for that pattern: "`###.###.###.###.xml`".

For further learning, read [Java's Pattern docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: how to make the syntax also recognize patterns like this #.#.#.#.xml ??? (also ##.#.###.#.xml should work etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
string.matches("[1-9.]+\\.xml")
```

should do it.

- `[1-9.]+` matches one or more digits between 1 and 9 and/or periods. (`+` means "one or more", `*` means "zero or more", `?` means "zero or one").
- `\.xml` matches `.xml`. Since `.` means "any character" in a regex, you need to escape it if you want it to mean a literal period: `\.` (and since this is in a Java string, the backslash itself needs to be escaped by doubling).

Comment: could you explain this a bit to me? whats the "+" for and the "\\"? Also why is there a "." inside the "[1-9]"

Comment: read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: this worked: [1.-9.]+\\.xml thank you for your help and explanation I will accept it

Comment: Note that that code will not match your exact pattern, and will give positives for, for example, "11.2222222.xml" and even "..xml" alone. Broad matches are **usually** (but not always) unrecommended.